# Reformat Pandas Data Frame with 1 Column's Values as Columns and other Columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` structured like:

```
name   date   A   B   C
n1     07/01  a   b   c
n1     06/01  aa  bb  cc
n1     05/01  aaa bbb ccc
...
```

I need to structure the dataframe so it looks like:

```
name   letters   05/01   06/01   07/01
n1     A        aaa     aa      a
n1     B        bbb     bb      b
n1     C        ccc     cc      c
...
```

I can pull all the columns into a new row using `melt()` from `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.melt(df, id_vars=["name"], var_name = "letters")
```

Which yields:

```
name   letters   value
n1     date      05/01
n1     date      06/01
n1     date      07/01
n1     A         aaa 
n1     A         aa
n1     A         a
n1     B         bbb   
n1     B         bb
n1     B         b
n1     C         ccc
n1     C         cc
n1     C         c    
...
```

Now how can I pivot this out by 'date' to get my desired structure?

I wasn't sure how I can apply `df.pivot()` on the 'date' rows in my 'letters' column. Any suggestions or alternate steps?

Comment: would `pd.pivot_table(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name', 'date']), index=['name', 'variable'], columns='date', aggfunc=sum)` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1 = df.drop('name', 1).set_index('date').rename_axis('letters', 1).sort_index(1, ascending=1).T.reset_index()
df1.set_index(pd.Index(['n1'] * len(df1), name='name')).reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @MaxU The problem is df.name is of length 3.  It is only coincidence (I think) that there are also 3 dated columns.  Because it's the same across the 3 rows, I'm guessing it's a label for the whole dataframe.  The way I've done it, it will grow if there happens to be more dated columns.

Comment: yes, you are right, that wasn't smart of me! Where did you define `df2`?

Comment: The dataframe contains more rows, this is just an example.  There is also an n2, n3, n4... etc.  Likewise there are more dates, but every name has the same number of dates.  I'm just trying to find a generalized solution to get the DF in the format I need using the available DF reshaping functions in Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to preserve my other answer, but I think this is a better answer.

```
tpose = lambda df: df.drop('name', 1).set_index('date').T
df.groupby('name', as_index=True).apply(tpose)
```

[image]

There are tweaks to be made to get to the final format you might want but I think it's uglier.

---

With tweaks

```
tpose = lambda df: df.drop('name', 1).set_index('date').T
df1 = df.groupby('name', as_index=True).apply(tpose)
df1.rename_axis(['name', 'letters']).reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

[image]

This is fully generalizable to whatever length dataset you have and any variable values in `'name'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 pd.concat([df[["name"]],df.iloc[:,1:].set_index("date").T.reset_index()],axis= 1 ).rename(columns = {'index':'letter'})

  name letter 07/01 06/01 05/01
0   n1      A     a    aa   aaa
1   n1      B     b    bb   bbb
2   n1      C     c    cc   ccc
```